# CookComputing xmlrpc how do I map a xml parameter name with a space in it?

Tags: xml-rpc, xml-rpc.net

How do I map a xml parameter name with a space in it?

I need the parameter named "build date" to be "builddate".

```
public struct ShowVersion
{
    public string version;
    public string builddate;
}
```

The xml response which I cannot change:

```
<methodresponse>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
        <struct>
          <member>
            <name>
              version
            </name>
            <value>
              <string>
                1.0.0.58964
              </string>
            </value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>
              build date
            </name>
            <value>
              <string>
                Dec 30 2015 12:32:04
              </string>
            </value>
          </member>
        </struct>
      </value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodresponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue using this XmlRpcMember.

```
public struct ShowVersion
{
    public string version;
    [XmlRpcMember("build date")]
    public string builddate;
}
```